# Why is one item in my header taking up so much space, and why is my list not being displayed inline?

Tags: html, css, navbar, web-deployment-project

I'm creating a website for a school project using HTML, CSS, and JS. Currently, I'm trying to create a navigation bar but am running into some issues with what I think is to do with flex-boxes. I want my logo to be positioned to the far left, the contact button far right, and the rest of the items in the middle. using inspect on edge, I can see that the logo is taking up lots of space when I don't think I assigned it to do so. please forgive me if I've missed something simple, complete web dev beginner here. [image: What i want my nav bar to look like]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(91, 117, 140);
}

main{
    background-color: #d6c7de;
    min-height: 75vh;
}

footer{
    min-height: 10vh;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

li, a, button{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px 10%;
    max-height: 15vh;
}

.logo {
    transform: scale(0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right:auto ;
   
}

.links{
    list-style: none;
}

.links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.links li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;

}

.links li a:hover {
    color: #0088a9;
    
}

button{
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color:rgba(0,136,169,1) ;
    border: none;
    border-radius:50px ;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,136,169,0.8) ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Womxn Skate History</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Stylesheet.CSS">
</head>
<body>
    <header> 
        <img class="logo" src="media/logo-1.svg" alt="Logo">

        <nav>
            <ul class="links">
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Skaters.html">Skaters</a></li>
                <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="About_me.html">About me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Contact</button></a>
        </header>
    </body> 

    <main>
        MAIN CONTENT
    </main>

    <footer>
        Footer
    </footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add width to your logo!